# Showing martingale property

Tags: probability, martingales

Here is the scenario I am presented with. I am supposed to show it is a martingale:

[image]

Here is what I have done so far. I am fairly sure it is correct, I just don't know how to simplify it.

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It looks like you are on the right track. Here's a hint, what is $E( S_n )$ for any $n$? More importantly, if you have two r.v. X and Y and X is F_n measurable, then E(XY|F_n) = X E(Y|F_n). Notice that $S_m$ is independent of $S_{m+n}-S_m$.